Jupyterbook: why is Math not rendering in Sphinx theorem environment?
I have a simple Jupyter-book with one notebook.
My _config.yml file includes the following lines:
# Add latex packages
parse:
  myst_enable_extensions:
    # don't forget to list any other extensions you want enabled,
    # including those that are enabled by default!
    - amsmath

# Sphinx proofs
sphinx:
  extra_extensions:
    - sphinx_proof



Then in my .ipynb file I have some Markdown with the following code:
````{prf:definition} Convergence of a sequence
:label: convergence-sequence
A sequence $(a_n)$ converges to a real number $a$ if, for every number $\epsilon> 0$, there exists ...````

The definition environment is rendered properly, but the math is not (i.e., it shows $(a_n)$ etc.).
I cannot seem to find clues in the documentation, which I have followed carefully.
Is there anything I am obviously missing?
